# Laravel - Deploy app on Heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku, command-line-interface, http-status-code-403

I am trying to deploy laravel application on heroku. I followed the videos on [heroku](http://heroku.com) homepage for deploying a php application. I currently get a `403 error, You don't have permission to access / on this server.` How can I change the app permissions in order to run it correctly?

Also how can I access the app from the terminal to apply any changes if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long time since I use Heroku, but the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#setting-the-document-root) has what you need. You are getting a 403 because it is likely you are not setting the web root. By default the web root is `/` which is restricted. In Laravel you need it to be `/public`

Add a `Procfile` to the root of your Laravel project and add the following line to it:

`web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/`

The second part of your question can be achieved by running `heroku run bash` from the terminal. You may need to specify your app name. However it should be mentioned that its likely your changes would be over written next time you deploy your app.